# Xamarin - Android - MarkerOptions.SetTitle does no update

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to update my marker label (Title) on my map. But it doesn't work.
I don't have that much code to share, it is quite simple :

```
pin = userMarkers[userPosition.User._id];
pin.SetTitle(userPosition.User.Username);
pin.SetPosition(new LatLng(userPosition.Position.Latitude, userPosition.Position.Longitude));
```

Does anyone have the same issue ?

Thank you,
Alek

Comment: Create a new marker and replace the old one

Comment: Are you sure that the omitted code is OK? It seems to me that `userMarkers` could be a list of pins you are managing, but that doesn't guarantee that your code elsewhere is actually adding them to the map (or that the pins in your list are the same instance references). Does the pin actually move to the updated location?